# Trouble saving data to a text file

Tags: python, file

when I try to write data to a file I get no errors but when I try to read it back nothing is in the file. What am I doing wrong?

```
test = open('/Users/MYUSER/Desktop/test.txt', 'r+')

test.write("RANDOME STRING\n")

test.read()

''
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the file pointer to the start of the file using [`file.seek`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) before calling `.read()`. When you write something to a file, the file pointer moves to the end of file, that's why calling `.read()` on the file object was returning an empty string.

**Demo:**

```
>>> test = open('abc1', 'r+')
>>> test.write('foo')
>>> test.read()
''
>>> test.seek(0)
>>> test.read()
'foo'
```